# not succeded to retrieve user personal information from facebook on android app

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to retrieve in my android app(in which I have facebook integrated ) the personal information for the logged in user.

For this I have `2 buttons`:

```
Button tweet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_post);
Button information = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_information);
```

The first button when pressed does a login like this:

```
tweet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                postMessage();

            }
        });
```

where `postMessage()` looks like:

```
   public void postMessage() {

        if (facebookConnector.getFacebook().isSessionValid()) {
            postMessageInThread();
        } else {
            SessionEvents.AuthListener listener = new SessionEvents.AuthListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAuthSucceed() {
                    postMessageInThread();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAuthFail(String error) {

                }
            };
            SessionEvents.addAuthListener(listener);
            facebookConnector.login();
        }
    }
```

After logging I have the second `button-information`

```
            information.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
                String accessToken = mFacebook.getAccessToken();

                try
                {
                        params.putString("format", "json");
                        params.putString("access_token", accessToken);

                        String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me";
                        String response = Util.openUrl(url, "GET", params);
                 try{
                        JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                        String name = json.getString("name");
                        String fname = json.getString("first_name");

                     }
                    catch(FacebookError e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }     




            }
        });
```

When pressed the button information I wanna retrieve the personal user information like `name` and `first_name`.

I tried to retrieve the user's personal information by using this:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/me".
```

But when I press the second button nothing happens.Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have [downloaded the latest version](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk). And when you have logged in and stored `AuthenticationToken` to your `SharedPreferences`.
Then make a call to the `"me"` using `request()` function of `Facebook` class something like this.

```
String resp = facebookConnector.getFacebook().request("me");
JSONObject me = Util.parseJson(resp);
String name = json.getString("name");
String fname = json.getString("first_name");
```

You have to just put `"me"` String to the request, The remaining URL will be automatically added by their `Util` class.

Comment: I have a question related to this.There must be separate buttons for trying to login and requesting personal info like Ady did?Isn't there a way to do it so after logg in the personal info to be loaded without preessing buttons....I mean the info to appear automatically?Thanks

Comment: Well see Ady has a method to post a message to wall. Where he first check that the session is valid or not if it is valid he can post a message to wall, else he get the Authentication from the user with a callback(i.e `SessionEvents.AuthListener`) and after successful Authentication he then post the message to wall. You can directly call this method without calling your login method as it will be automatically called if needed. Same technique can be used to get user info from a single button (i.e `F-JOIN`) by coding a `postMessage()` like method, where you will put `"me"` functionality.

Comment: Don't u know a tutorial with things like this?I mean I understand what u  are saying but still I'm not able to write code by myself!Thank u:)